# Creating dynamic hyperlinks with VLookup using excel

Tags: excel, hyperlink, spreadsheet, vlookup

I've searched for a solution for this issue I'm having but I haven't been able to find anything.

Let's say I'm working out of 2 worksheets, A and B.

Worksheet B has a cell I'll call Price. Price depends on a certain input, which comes from the AJ column in worksheet A. Price gets a dollar value from column BW inside of worksheet A.

Worksheet A has a column (AJ) and a column (BW).

My question is this. How can I click on the cell in worksheet B (Price) and be redirected or "hyperlinked" to the appropriate cell in Worksheet A column BW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place formulas within the hyperlink function

```
 =HYPERLINK("[book1]SheetA!BW" & MATCH(C3,AJ:AJ,0),INDEX(BW:BW,MATCH(C3,AJ:AJ,0)))
```

In the above

- Hyperlink is the main function
- "[book1]SheetA!BW" - you would change to your workbook name. this is telling it which sheet and column to link to
- MATCH(C3,AJ:AJ,0) - This looks for your input value in column AJ and returns a number, that number is the row number. you will need to select the whole column or the match rows wont line up with the real row numbers
- c3 would be the input for your vlookup, or (index match which is what I used)
- INDEX(BW:BW,MATCH(C3,AJ:AJ,0))) this is an index match that returns the value of BW you looked up into the price cell on sheet B. It will show as the text